# How can I use lambda to drop column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

What I saw from the web is coding like:

```
train_df = train_df.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)
test_df = test_df.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)
```

But I want to make it shorter, so I try to code like:

```
train_df,test_df=lambda x:x.drop(['Ticket','Cabin'],axis=1)
```

And I get the error:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

I want to know if it's possible to use lambda like my way or the first coding is already the best one?

Comment: Why not just `for df in (train_df, test_df): df.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1, inplace=True)` - although it's not really any shorter...

Answer (score 0):

So, I can see the logic for wanting something like this. Here's what I'd do in that situation:

```
#put your dataframes into a tuple
dfs = (train_df, test_df)
```

could be any iterable really, just to save typing if you want to add more dataframes to the process

```
dfs = map(lambda x: x.drop(['Ticket','Cabin'], axis=1), dfs)
```

Which will do exactly as you wish.

Note if you're on Python3, `map` is lazy, so it would be kinda easier (and more pythonic generally) to do:

```
dfs = [x.drop(['Ticket','Cabin'], axis=1) for x in dfs]
```

For completeness' sake, the reason you were getting an error is because the right hand side of:

```
train_df,test_df=lambda x:x.drop(['Ticket','Cabin'],axis=1)
```

Is just a function, and isn't iterating over your dataframes.

Comment: That's pyhonic! Helped me to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept/upvote  the answer if it solved your problem